# How search LINQ with many parametrs in one column?

Tags: linq-to-sql

For example have this table:

```
Name | BodyType
----------------
John  | 1
Ted   | 2
Daniel| 3
George| 4
```

I my app i check "1" "2" and "3" checkbox. And i should find 3 rows (John, Ted, Daniel) and NOT George. How can i get this query in LINQ? (not use `where p.BodyType!=4`)
Use logic **OR**

```
var all = dataContext.Users;
foreach (searchParameter in search)
  ...?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the required IDs into a `List<int>` and then `Contains`:

```
var bodyTypes = GetBodyTypesFromSearchParameters();
var query = dataContext.Users.Where(user => bodyTypes.Contains(user.BodyType));
```

Comment: And if i have languages (in one column) Languages: 1,2,3,4;1,2,3. and i need 1,2,3 and not 4 (varchar)

Comment: @Dmitriy: If you've got one column specifying multiple values, I'd say you need to revisit your database design. Implement many-to-many relationships with a mapping table instead. Using a comma-separated list is going to make things really awkward.

Comment: I know. Unfortunately this is not my DB and I have to work with such ugly design :( thx you

Comment: And if i have table one-to-many: `ID` and second table `UserID|LanguageID`. How can i select OR query?

Comment: @Dmitriy: I'm afraid it's not very clear what you mean just from comments. I suggest you start a new question with a clear explanation instead of trying to squeeze multiple questions into one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871186/how-linq-many-to-many-with-or-search my question

Answer (score 1):

Essentially you need to get your parameters into an Enumerable container and then use LINQ's Contains method when iterating through your table with the Where method:

```
    var parameters = new[] { 1, 2, 3};
    var list = new[] { new { Name = "John", BodyType = 1 }, new { Name = "Ted", BodyType = 2 }, new { Name = "Daniel", BodyType = 3 }, new { Name = "George", BodyType = 4 } };
    var result = list.Where(c => parameters.Contains(c.BodyType));
```